# Using buttons from Bootstrap 2 in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 2 and thinking to migrate to the newer Bootstrap 3. However, I don't find the buttons in Version 3 as appealing as those from Version 2. Is there any simple way to use those nice buttons from v2 inside v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exclude buttons and download bootstrap from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ , you can then copy the btn sytles from bootstrap 2.x.x stylesheet and use those in your new website which uses bs3.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Am I right to put the v2 styles before v3 in my HTML?

Comment: No. You have to put bs2 button styles after bs3 css reference.

Comment: Hm ... I was worried that bs2 styles could break some of the bs3, will they not? Im my simple test example both ways work but it is really very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just include the `bootstrap-theme[.min].css` file that's an optional part of Bootstrap itself.

The Bootstrap Theme includes nice gradients etc. to make Bootstrap v3 look more skeuomorphic like Bootstrap v2. Here's the official example of it in action: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

Comment: Interesting, it really looks different but then ... seems like the colours are not as vivid as v2.